# Accessing public fields in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, field, public

I've tried the following sample code:

```
    #import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

    @interface example
    {
        @public NSString* name;
    }
    @end

    @implementation example @end

    int main()
    {
        example* me;
        me->name = @"World";
    }
```

And it appears my code hates me at this point.  I do understand how much of a bad idea it is to make a field public, but I'm not sure why I'm getting an error at that last line in main().

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: Oh wow.  I'm stupid.  Forgot to allocate memory.  EDIT: Looks like someone noticed.

Comment: **DO NOT ACCESS INSTANCE VARIABLES LIKE THIS**   Use an accessor method.  *Always.*

Comment: @bbum Yes, I did note how bad of a practice that was in my original post.  Just felt like understanding how to do this, just because I felt like getting to know the innards of this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating or initializing your `me` variable. You probably want to inherit from `NSObject` and then use this:

```
example *me = [[example alloc] init]
```

At the very least you need to `alloc` it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a lot wrong here

You class should subclass `NSObject` so it should be declared as

```
@interface example : NSObject
{
    @public NSString* name;
}

@end
```

---

Next you actually need an instance of the class to get at it's values e.g.

```
example *me = [[example alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", me->name);
```

---

Next classes are named starting with an uppercase letter and normally have a prefix e.g. I would use

```
PSExample
```

---

Next please don't access instance variables like this, you should make your objects state available through accessors rather than give direct access.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your variable before you can access it. Also you should derive your class from `NSObject`.

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

@interface example : NSObject
{
    @public NSString* name;
}
@end

@implementation example @end

int main()
{
    example* me = [[example alloc] init];
    me->name = @"World";
}
```